# Deleting an item from ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement a function to delete the selected item from the list on long press after confirmation from the user to delete ('Yes' button and 'No' button). I am using Inkwell.

I tried a few various ways but couldn't find anything.

One similar post I found but it was not useful.

Note: I don't want to use Dismissable

Here is the code: -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smoorapplication/src/services/api.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';

class BodyFunctionCard extends StatefulWidget{
  const BodyFunctionCard({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BodyFunctionCardHPState createState() => _BodyFunctionCardHPState();
}

class _BodyFunctionCardHPState extends State<BodyFunctionCard>{
  List<bool> isExpanded = List.generate(100, (index) => false);
  List<bool> isAccepted = List.generate(100,(index) => false);
  List<bool> isPicked = List.generate(100,(index) => false);
  List<bool> isArrived = List.generate(100,(index) => false);
  List<bool> isDelRet = List.generate(100,(index) => false);
  List<bool> isFinished = List.generate(100,(index) => false);
  List<bool> countfin = List.generate(100,(index) => false);
  List<double> lpind = List.generate(100, (index) => 0.0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Card(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: apiGetOrder(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none || snapshot.hasData == null){
                return const Center(child:
                Text('Loading data . . . !'),);
              }return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(child:
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 380,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        const SizedBox(height: 3.5,),
                        Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 370,
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(220,220,220,2.0),
                          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Text('  ${snapshot.data[index].orderNumber}', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            const SizedBox(width: 130,),
                            LinearPercentIndicator(
                              width: 100,
                              lineHeight: 15,
                              percent: lpind[index],
                              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                              progressColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                            Text('  ${snapshot.data[index].orderNumber}', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                          ],),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          RichText(text: const TextSpan(
                              children: [
                                WidgetSpan(
                                    child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),child: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.orange, size: 18,),)
                                )
                              ]
                          )),
                          const Text('PICKUP LOCATION', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),)
                        ],),
                        const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          Text('        ${snapshot.data[index].lineItems[0].originLocation.name} ${snapshot.data[index].lineItems[0].originLocation.address1}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                          )
                        ],),
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          Text('        ${snapshot.data[index].lineItems[0].originLocation.address2}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                          )
                        ],),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          RichText(text: const TextSpan(
                              children: [
                                WidgetSpan(
                                    child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),child: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.lightGreen, size: 18,),)
                                )
                              ]
                          )),
                          const Text('DELIVERY LOCATION', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),)
                        ],),
                        const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          Text('        ${snapshot.data[index].lineItems[0].originLocation.name} ${snapshot.data[index].lineItems[0].originLocation.address1}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                          )
                        ],),
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          Text('        ${snapshot.data[index].lineItems[0].originLocation.address2}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                          )
                        ],)
                      ],),
                    ),
                      onTap: (){
                        setState(() {
                          isExpanded[index] = !isExpanded[index];
                        });
                      },
                      onLongPress: (){
                        setState(() {
                          // I want to delete the item at the current index.
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  ],
                );
            }
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to Flutter, I will help others when I gain some knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

have your tried this?

```
yourList.remove(index);
```

or

```
yourList.removerWhere(()=> yourSnapshotData == theSnaspshotData);
```

Comment: I don't know what is the name of my list. Can you please tell me from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List items = [
    {"name": "item one", "color": Colors.red},
    {"name": "item two", "color": Colors.blue},
    {"name": "item three", "color": Colors.yellow},
    {"name": "item four", "color": Colors.pink},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return InkWell(
              onLongPress: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text("DELETE?"),
                          actions: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  items.removeAt(index);
                                  setState(() {});
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                })
                          ],
                        ));
              },
              child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Text(items[index]['name']),
                  color: items[index]['color']));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have 2 questions:

1. Regarding button with long press option. For this, you can use `RawMaterialButton`. Below is the example.

```
child: RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: (){},   // if you want an action on single press, you can write here
  onLongPress: () => _confirmationBox(snapshot.data[index]), // call a function on long press
),
```

2. You want to show a confirmation box. For this, you can use `showDialog`. See the below example.

```
void _confirmationBox(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: const Text('On pressing OK it will get deleted'),
        actions: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                snapshot.data.removeAt(index);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Ok',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){},
              child: const Text(
                'Cancel',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

NOTE: the better approach is to use the id of the data to remove it from the List rather than using an index value.